# PreparedStatement.close throw new IllegalStateException

Tags: vert.x

```
private static void execute(MySQLPool jdbcClient, String sql, JsonArray params, Handler<AsyncResult<RowSet<Row>>> handler) {
        jdbcClient.getConnection(res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                SqlConnection connection = res.result();
                connection.prepare(sql, ar -> {
                    if (ar.succeeded()) {
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ar.result();
                        preparedStatement.query().execute(Tuple.tuple(params.getList()), ar2 -> {
                            if (ar2.succeeded()) {
                                RowSet<Row> rows = ar2.result();
                                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(rows));
                            } else {
//                              logger.error("----############---- sql:"+sql+" params:"+params.toString()+" "+ar2.cause().getMessage());
                                handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar2.cause().getMessage()));
                            }
                            preparedStatement.close();// throw new IllegalStateException
                            connection.close();
                        });
                    } else {
                        logger.error("----############---- prepare error sql:" + sql + " params:" + params.toString() + " " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                        handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(ar.cause().getMessage()));
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ar.result();
                        if (preparedStatement != null){
                            preparedStatement.close();
                        }
                        connection.close();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                logger.error("----############---- getConnection error sql:" + sql + " params:" + params.toString() + " " + res.cause().getMessage());
                handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(res.cause().getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }
```

There is a probability of {throw new IllegalStateException} when executing {Preparedstatement.close} code

<vertx.version>3.9.8</vertx.version>

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.schedule(SocketConnectionBase.java:137)
 at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.ConnectionPool$PooledConnection.schedule(ConnectionPool.java:129)
 at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.Connection.schedule(Connection.java:41)
 at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.PreparedStatementImpl.close(PreparedStatementImpl.java:176)
 at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.PreparedStatementImpl.close(PreparedStatementImpl.java:136)
 at com.motu.vertx.module.utility.mysql.MysqlTool.lambda$null$0(MysqlTool.java:130)
```

Comment: I don't think you should close the `preparedStatement` inside of `execute { ... }`